# How do I escape tilde (~) in batch file on replacing it with a different character?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The script can replace certain characters to specified character in file names, but is not working for tilde `~`.

Below two parts are working perfectly.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*_*) do (
    set file=%%a
    ren "!file!" "!file:_=A!"
)
for %%a in (*-*) do (
    set file=%%a
    ren "!file!" "!file:-=B!"
)
```

But this part is not working.

```
for %%a in (*~*) do (
    set file=%%a
    ren "!file!" "!file:~=C!"
)
```

Why is replacement of `~` not working and how to solve that?

Comment: You are using [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) syntax (like `!file:search=replac!`), which does not allow a search string to begin with `~`, because then it would be confused with [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) syntax (like `!file:~pos,len!`)...

Comment: Circumvent the issue @aschipfl describes by splitting the file name with a nested `for /f` =>`for %%a in (*~*) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=~" %%b in ("%%a") do Ren "%%a" "%%b%%C"`

Comment: @LotPings, I was typing an answer while you were commenting; same thought at the same time? I am scared now... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You are using [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) syntax (like `!file:search=replac!`), which does not allow a search string to begin with `~`, because then it would be confused with [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) syntax (like `!file:~pos,len!`).

What you can do is using [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split your file names at the `~` character:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims=~ eol=~" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D "*~*"') do (
    if not "%%J" == "" ren "%%I~%%J" "%%IC%%J"
)
```

This works only if there is a single `~` character and such is not at the first position.

If there is more than one `~` character and at any position, it becomes a bit more complex:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "*~*" ^| find "~"') do (
    set "FILE=%%F" & set "EXT=%%~xF"
    call :SUB NAME "%%~nF" C
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ren "!FILE!" "!NAME!!EXT!"
    endlocal
)
exit /B

:SUB
    set "#RET=%~1"
    set "STR=%~2"
    set "CHR=%~3"
    set "LEFT=" & set "REST="
    if not defined STR goto :NEXT
:LOOP
    set "REST=%STR:*~=%"
    if "%REST%" == "%STR%" goto :NEXT
    for /F "delims=~ eol=~" %%E in ("_%STR%") do set "LEFT=%%E"
    set "STR=%LEFT:~1%%CHR%%REST%"
    goto :LOOP
:NEXT
    set "%#RET%=%STR%"
    exit /B
```

The sub-routine `:SUB` splits the file name string at every `~` in a loop and rebuilds it by replacing `~` with the specified character.

The filter `| find "~"` (as well as the `if not "%%J" == ""` condition in the first approach) are needed because [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) matches also [short file names](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html), which usually contain a `~` character. If such 8.3 file names are disabled on your system, these additional code portions might be removed (although they do not harm).